# In determining sound beam steering angle, where does a constant of 0.514 come from?

Tags: waves, acoustics, diffraction

I've read in some sources (like [this](http://www.olympus-ims.com/en/ndt-tutorials/transducers/pa-beam/steering/), among some other) that for determining sound beam steering angle in a phased-shift array system, it is using a formula of:

$$\theta = \arcsin (0.514 \lambda\mkern-6mu^{_-}\mkern-12mu^{_-} / e)$$

Where does this constant of 0.514 come from? Is it related in some way to the analogy of diffraction grating?

Comment: This site has latex-like formatting available, which is useful for displaying equations. I've edited this in for you (though getting a barred lambda proved challenging, and what I did ended up being a bit of a hack!). Consider using this in future posts ([tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)).

Comment: @KyleOman you might want to learn about unicode in mathjax: `\unicode{0x19b}` shows up as $\unicode{0x19b}$. Found by using [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com)... hat off for the hack though!

Comment: @Floris ahh thanks! I found the unicode character, but couldn't figure out how to use it in the (relatively limited) mathjax environment. And detexify didn't know about it.

Comment: @KyleOman well you learnt at least one Thing today ... That puts you ahead in the game. PS I learnt too: thanks, Google!

Answer (score 2):

It comes from [point spread function](http://web.ipac.caltech.edu/staff/fmasci/home/astro_refs/PSFtheory.pdf) theory in optics and 0.514 is the factor used for specifically considering the part of your beam that encircles half the power (-6 dB of peak). It is derived from the [Airy Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function)